# Looker Studio - Need to verify setup of filtering out traffic that selects a specific external link

Tags: looker-studio, google-analytics-4

Need to verify that I have a filter set up correctly to remove sessions where a specific external link was selected. current settings: Exclude Full Page URL then added the full URL. it seems to remove session counts that appear to be correct but then I cannot locate this URL in the outbound link report when trying to verify the inverse.

Tried to verify via outbound link report but it doesn't appear to be configured with GA4 so why is it able to filter in session count but not be reported anywhere else?